# Disable toolbar scrolling when pressing on it

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-toolbar

I tried to find someone with the same question but didn't really know what to search for. If someone else finds a simliar question, just let me know!

I've implemented the toolbar from the design library as follows:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainTabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:tabGravity="fill" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

and the toolbar layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar   
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/mainToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

The AppBarLayout is a direct child to the CoordinatorLayout. Below the AppBar I have a RecyclerView that correctly lets the AppBar collapse when scrolling up.

However I'm able to press directly on the AppBar and then move my finger up and that way the toolbar collapses even though my RecyclerView is completely empty. I can expand it again by scrolling down on the toolbar again. This behavior doesn't happen when scrolling where the RecyclerView is.

I hope my problem is understandable. I'm using version 25.1 of the support library. 
Thanks!

Edit: I tried the solutions below. Didn't change anything. Down below I added a video to show what my issue is. So it's really about the situation when the screen is not full (so no elements from the RecyclerView goes off the screen): If that's the case I don't want the Toolbar to hide at all. In other words: Only hide the toolbar if any elements from RecyclerView go off the screen.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzrw-IuZ9USuMURVVkRfb3dkRTQ/view?usp=sharing

If any more code is needed from my side just let know.

Comment: I think you are looking for fling behavior. Google it you will find readymade code

Comment: I dont think that's my issue. If you look at the video  (first part): The RecyclerView is not going off the screen but the Toolbar still hides when scrolling up. I don't want that. @SouravGanguly

Answer (score 0):

Try this
The entire project is at this location:
https://github.com/slidenerd/Android-Design-Support-Library-Demo

The below code works for me(This Git project belongs to slidenered. Thanx to him):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="slidenerd.vivz.navigationviewdemo.FourthActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/root_coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="192dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/rsz_bg_cover"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/app_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabTextColor="#EEE" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:fabSize="mini" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer" />
```

Comment: Didn't solve my issue. I edited my question maybe this helps

Answer (score 0):

if u want to fixed the `toolbar` when `appbar`  is scrolled

try this:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    ...
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            ...
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:titleEnabled="false">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

put your `toolbar` under a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and `app:titleEnabled="false"`

By setting it to false, you'll get the desired behaviour. The title stays fixed at the top of the screen.

you can do it programetically also:

```
CollapsingToolbarLayout.setTitleEnabled(false);
```

Comment: didn't work. I edited my question and added a video. Maybe I've been misunderstood? Thanks for your help!